# Make countdown timer go from 10sec to 1sec

Tags: java, android, timer, countdowntimer

I have a CountDown timer that counts down from 10000ms to 0ms in increments of 1 second each to make a button clickable after 10 seconds. Although the timer is accurate and does what the code says, I would like to change the way the seconds are expressed but I don't know how.

java:

```
void startTimer() {
    cTimer = new CountDownTimer(10000, 1000) {
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            c.setText("Please wait " + millisUntilFinished/1000 + " seconds");
            thx.setText(millisUntilFinished/1000 + "");
            thx.setAlpha(.5f);
            thx.setClickable(false);

        }
        public void onFinish() {
        c.setText("done");
            thx.setText("ready");
            thx.setAlpha(1f);
            thx.setClickable(true);
        }
    };
    cTimer.start();
}
```

Outputted (Every second): `9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, (still 1), ready`

Desired: (Every second): `10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, ready`

Thanks,

B

**EDIT:**

I added 1 to the countdown, `thx.setText(((millisUntilFinished/1000) + 1) + "");`

New output: `10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4 ,3 , 2, (Still 2), ready`

Closer... but not quite.

Comment: What can you see for ` thx.setText(millisUntilFinished + "");` ? Without division

Comment: 9901, 8901, 7900, 6897, 5896, 4890, 3890, 2889, 1888, (1888), ready

Comment: How about instantiating the start time e.g. 10000 above the timer and then on tick you could just decrement that value by 1000 and then divide that number for your output. This would give you much more control and precision.

Comment: @J. Knight Simple yet effective solution that I should have thought of before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just my investigation on CountDownTimer when I used CountDownTimer 
 few month before and its work fine in my application.

```
public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished)
```

This millisUntilFinished will give the remaining time in millisecond, and last 1000 millisecond is to call onFinish() method, So onTick method will get called until the remaining time is more than (1000(for OnFinish)  + 1000(for counter)) milliseconds, if the last remaining millisecond is less than 2000millisecond it will skip the onTick() and it will directly call onFinish() when timer ends. For more details just see [Handler](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/java/android/os/CountDownTimer.java#handleMessage) method in this source.

So the main problem is when we give some X(our case 10000)milliseconds, but to start the counter it's taking some 50 to 150 milliseconds, So if we add that millisecond in our total time we will get the counter until end,

So you can try like this, Nothing change just I added 150 milliseconds in your total time.

```
void startTimer() {
    cTimer = new CountDownTimer(10150, 1000) {
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            c.setText("Please wait " + millisUntilFinished/1000 + " seconds");
            thx.setText(millisUntilFinished/1000 + "");
            thx.setAlpha(.5f);
            thx.setClickable(false);

        }
        public void onFinish() {
        c.setText("done");
            thx.setText("ready");
            thx.setAlpha(1f);
            thx.setClickable(true);
        }
    };
    cTimer.start();
}
```

Let me know if its works or not, If you ask me why you are not using Handler, I can say [CountDownTime](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/java/android/os/CountDownTimer.java) internally using Handler.

Comment: @MuthukrishnanRajendran  Thanks, I read your answer. But I think it is not quite true because with each `onTick` call it eats up another 2-3 milliseconds. So if you repeat long enough (say 300 or 500 times) even those 150 milliseconds which you add upfront won't do the trick. Also, what you suggest is just workaround which basically confirms there's a bug there. Otherwise... yeah, it's a smart workaround to add 150 millis upfront. Thanks for the hint.

Answer (score 1):

Try this one for counter:

```
   public void CountDown() {
    final TextView textic = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvConuter);

    CountDownTimer Count = new CountDownTimer(10000, 1000) {
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            long str = millisUntilFinished / 1000;
            String TimeFinished = String.valueOf(str);
            textic.setText(TimeFinished);
        }
        public void onFinish() {
            textic.setText("STOP");

        }
    };
    Count.start();
}
```

This worked perfectly for me.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use `Timer()` or `Handler()` class.

```
int tick = 0;
    Handler handler = new Handler();
    Runnable r = new Runnable() {void run(){
if (i < 10) {
handler.postDelayed()}
else {
//finished
tick = 0;
}}};
```

starting:

`handler.post(r);`

Answer (score 0):

```
new CountDownTimer(10000, 1000) {

public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
    mTextField.setText("seconds: " + millisUntilFinished / 1000);
   //here you can have your logic to set text to edittext
}

public void onFinish() {
    mTextField.setText("done!");
}

}.start();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private void countDownTimer(int seconds) {

    countDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(seconds * 1000L, 1000 - 500) {

        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {

            //Convert to seconds
            int secondsUnillFinished = (int) (millisUntilFinished / 1000);

            //Set text to seconds
            textView.setText(String.valueOf(secondsUnillFinished));

            //At zero, do something
            if(secondsUnillFinished == 0) {
                countDownTimer.cancel();
                textView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            }
        }

        @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
        public void onFinish() {
           //Dont put anything here
        }

    }.start();
}
```