# CountDownTimer bug Android

Tags: android

The object `CountDownTimer(30000,1000)` is supposed to call 
`onTick` for 30 secs on regular intervals of 1 sec.

First I was asking myself if `onTick` is called for the the time at the moment of 0 secs elapsed or at the moment of 1 second elapsed. Turns out the former is true (which I find kind of strange but let's say this is OK). 
So when we start the `CountDownTimer` the `onTick` is immediately called (and not after 1 sec).

Then... I was asking myself how many times it will call `onTick`. It should call it 30 times in my opinion (at 0 secs, at 1 sec, ... at 29 secs). Then at 30 secs it should call `onFinish` but not `onTick`.

But I tried it and `onTick` is called just 29 times. Why? Isn't this a bug?
This is a very basic example so I am surprised I am finding an issue in the very first test I am trying out.

See below: `--->DONE!!!` is printed from `onFinish`, the other printouts are from `onTick` and they are just 29 which is strange?! Note that in `onTick` and `onFinish` I am not doing any long lasting operations (I am just setting a text field's value and printing out this output below).

```
    07-04 08:05:04.567 2558-2951/net.fxfyfz.test019 W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to choose config with EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED, retrying without...
    07-04 08:05:04.567 2558-2951/net.fxfyfz.test019 D/OpenGLRenderer: Swap behavior 0
    07-04 08:05:04.616 2558-2558/net.fxfyfz.test019 W/art: Before Android 4.1, method int android.support.v7.widget.ListViewCompat.lookForSelectablePosition(int, boolean) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.widget.ListView
    07-04 08:05:35.731 2558-2558/net.fxfyfz.test019 I/net.fxfyfz.test019.MainActivity: --->29999
    07-04 08:05:36.732 2558-2558/net.fxfyfz.test019 I/net.fxfyfz.test019.MainActivity: --->28999
    07-04 08:05:37.733 2558-2558/net.fxfyfz.test019 I/net.fxfyfz.test019.MainActivity: --->27998
    07-04 08:05:38.734 2558-2558/net.fxfyfz.test019 I/net.fxfyfz.test019.MainActivity: --->26996
    07-04 08:05:39.737 2558-2558/net.fxfyfz.test019 I/net.fxfyfz.test019.MainActivity: --->25993
    07-04 08:05:40.740 2558-2558/net.fxfyfz.test019 I/net.fxfyfz.test019.MainActivity: --->24991
    07-04 08:05:41.742 2558-2558/net.fxfyfz.test019 I/net.fxfyfz.test019.MainActivity: --->23989
    07-04 08:05:42.743 2558-2558/net.fxfyfz.test019 I/net.fxfyfz.test019.MainActivity: --->22987
    07-04 08:05:43.746 2558-2558/net.fxfyfz.test019 I/net.fxfyfz.test019.MainActivity: --->21985
    07-04 08:05:44.748 2558-2558/net.fxfyfz.test019 I/net.fxfyfz.test019.MainActivity: --->20983
    07-04 08:05:45.751 2558-2558/net.fxfyfz.test019 I/net.fxfyfz.test019.MainActivity: --->19980
    07-04 08:05:46.751 2558-2558/net.fxfyfz.test019 I/net.fxfyfz.test019.MainActivity: --->18980
    07-04 08:05:47.752 2558-2558/net.fxfyfz.test019 I/net.fxfyfz.test019.MainActivity: --->17979
    07-04 08:05:48.755 2558-2558/net.fxfyfz.test019 I/net.fxfyfz.test019.MainActivity: --->16976
    07-04 08:05:49.756 2558-2558/net.fxfyfz.test019 I/net.fxfyfz.test019.MainActivity: --->15974
    07-04 08:05:50.759 2558-2558/net.fxfyfz.test019 I/net.fxfyfz.test019.MainActivity: --->14972
    07-04 08:05:51.761 2558-2558/net.fxfyfz.test019 I/net.fxfyfz.test019.MainActivity: --->13970
    07-04 08:05:52.764 2558-2558/net.fxfyfz.test019 I/net.fxfyfz.test019.MainActivity: --->12967
    07-04 08:05:53.766 2558-2558/net.fxfyfz.test019 I/net.fxfyfz.test019.MainActivity: --->11965
    07-04 08:05:54.769 2558-2558/net.fxfyfz.test019 I/net.fxfyfz.test019.MainActivity: --->10962
    07-04 08:05:55.771 2558-2558/net.fxfyfz.test019 I/net.fxfyfz.test019.MainActivity: --->9960
    07-04 08:05:56.771 2558-2558/net.fxfyfz.test019 I/net.fxfyfz.test019.MainActivity: --->8960
    07-04 08:05:56.780 2558-2563/net.fxfyfz.test019 I/art: Do partial code cache collection, code=29KB, data=30KB
    07-04 08:05:56.780 2558-2563/net.fxfyfz.test019 I/art: After code cache collection, code=29KB, data=30KB
    07-04 08:05:56.780 2558-2563/net.fxfyfz.test019 I/art: Increasing code cache capacity to 128KB
    07-04 08:05:57.773 2558-2558/net.fxfyfz.test019 I/net.fxfyfz.test019.MainActivity: --->7957
    07-04 08:05:58.776 2558-2558/net.fxfyfz.test019 I/net.fxfyfz.test019.MainActivity: --->6955
    07-04 08:05:59.778 2558-2558/net.fxfyfz.test019 I/net.fxfyfz.test019.MainActivity: --->5953
    07-04 08:06:00.780 2558-2558/net.fxfyfz.test019 I/net.fxfyfz.test019.MainActivity: --->4951
    07-04 08:06:01.782 2558-2558/net.fxfyfz.test019 I/net.fxfyfz.test019.MainActivity: --->3949
    07-04 08:06:02.783 2558-2558/net.fxfyfz.test019 I/net.fxfyfz.test019.MainActivity: --->2947
    07-04 08:06:03.785 2558-2558/net.fxfyfz.test019 I/net.fxfyfz.test019.MainActivity: --->1945
    07-04 08:06:05.733 2558-2558/net.fxfyfz.test019 I/net.fxfyfz.test019.MainActivity: --->DONE!!!
```

Comment: You can refer this [So answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44492812/900128)

Comment: @MuthukrishnanRajendran  Thanks, I read your answer. But I think it is not quite true because with each `onTick` call it eats up another 2-3 milliseconds. So if you repeat long enough (say 300 or 500 times) even those 150 milliseconds which you add upfront won't do the trick. Also, what you suggest is just workaround which basically confirms there's a bug there. Otherwise... yeah, it's a smart workaround to add 150 millis upfront. Thanks for the hint.

Comment: Yes, I agree with you, every tick it will take minimum 2 - 3 sec delayed, To start first tick it will take minimum 75 to 125 milliseconds, and in my example, I gave 10 sec only so only I gave 150milliseconds extra, I you have the counter with larger number you can add 125 + (n * 3) milliseconds extra. 125 is max time to start counter in safer side.